# How to access lower layer files in docker?

Tags: filesystems, docker, mount

I have two docker images, one provides files from a directory outside the services directory, and the other that service itself. So let `image1` be the one for outside files and let `image2` be the one containing the service.

`image1`'s dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:0.10.38
ADD . /opt/services/models
WORKDIR /opt/services/models
RUN npm install
VOLUME /opt/services/models
CMD ["node"]
```

`image2`'s dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM 127.0.0.1:5000/models:latest
ADD . /opt/serivces/app
WORKDIR /opt/serivces/app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 9001
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "app.js"]
```

I am trying to have it so `image2` can require the modules from `image1` however `/opt/services/models` does not seem to exist within `image2`. I have these containers run with kubernetes, which I specify the volume `image2` is to mount. Is there something I'm missing or can I just no access `image1`'s files?

**EDIT 1**

Oddly enough, when I created an `image3`, which is almost identical to image2, except it is adding a different directory, the directory from `image1` is present regardless of whether I specify the volume.

**EDIT 2**

I haven't actually found a solution to this, but I have found a workaround of having all Dockerfiles in the root of the project and adding any needed directory (this isn't great but it works). The only thing I have to do differently is `docker build -t 127.0.0.1:5000/imageX --file=./imageXDockerfile .` so that I can specify which image to build.